# How can I cast a a string to generic number using scala?

Tags: scala, generics

I'm trying to convert a generic string to a number using scala

```
object h extends App {
  def castTo[T](s: String): T = {
    s.asInstanceOf[T]
  }


  print(castTo[Int]("20"))
  print(castTo[Double]("20.1"))
}
```

the data:

name | value 
 a | "1"
 b | "2.123"
 c | "abd"

the usecase: 
riight now I'm exporting the data to the user a method for each conversion.
getNameAsDouble, getNameAsInteger and so forth.
I wish to do getNameT to save lot's of code and make it a bit more pretty and easy to read the doc.

so, in case a programmer does :
 getNameInt i want the program to print in this case: `1`
 getNameDouble i want the program to print in this case: `2.123`

in cpp i could use dynamic_cast. there a way to do so in scala?
( i also tried to do so in java but couldn't find a way)

p.s.
i've tried something like this, but i wandered if there is more generic way.

```
castTo[T] (s:String): T = {
...
case T instance of Integer => s.toInt
case T instance of Long => s.toLong
...
}
```

Comment: What you want to do is to **parse** the `String` into a generic `Number`, not to **cast** it. BTW, why do you want to do this? `String` already provides the `toInt`, `toDouble` & etc methods, why do you need to encapsulate all of them on a single method?

Comment: i'm exporiting an API to get data from source like this:
name | value 
a | "1"
b | "2.123"
c | "abd"
so the user of the api would do
getName[Int](name)

Comment: It would be good if you add that to your question with a broader explanation, example of use, expected output and what should happen if the types do not match.

Comment: i've edited the question. thank you for your comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it would be better if you can expand more on your use case.
But, this should do what you want.

```
def readAs[T](str: String)(implicit num: Numeric[T]): Option[T] =
  num.parseString(str)
```

Which you can test like:

```
readAs[Int]("10")
// res: Option[Int] = Some(10)

readAs[Double]("10")
// res: Option[Double] = Some(10.0)

readAs[Double]("10.0d")
// res: Option[Double] = Some(10.0)

readAs[Int]("10.0d")
// res: Option[Int] = None

readAs[Int]("blah")
// res: Option[Int] = None
```

Answer (score 1):

Scala is not javascript.  Scala is a real programming language with **types**.  **Strong** types even.  So, it treats conversions between types as what they really are: ***conversions***.  Not "casts".  So, the string will have to be parsed into a number. And if you wrap this parsing in a function, it is utterly wrong to call this conversion a "cast".

And no, you cannot cast a string to a number in C++ either. Not with a dynamic cast, nor with any other kind of cast. You also have to parse it in C++, because C++ is also a real programming language.

As for simplifying your pattern matching expression, you might be able to first parse the string into a double, and then use a generic cast to convert that double into a number of lesser precision, but I do not have a Scala compiler at hand to prove the concept.

Comment: This could be condensed to a comment instead of an answer as it really doesn't answer the question.